# Why do we still use Netbios aliases?

Tags: dns, netbios, fqdn

Why do we use Netbios alias names even when FQDN/DNS exist. Knowing the fact that Netbios is flat naming structure compared to the hierarchial naming way in FQDN and Netbios supports lesser number of nodes in the network compared to FQDN.
Other than interacting with Windows NT machines and machines running in Windows 95 or less why else is Netbios still used?

Answer (score 0):

NetBIOS is legacy of Wins. You are answering your own question : "interacting with Windows NT machines and machines running in Windows 95 or less ".

Also in a home network, for discovering machines, NetBIOS come more handy than DNS: Your computers at home are usually provided by DHCP with a  DNS IP address of your gateway (router) which forward any DNS requests to your ISP DNS server, it has no Machine (A) and Reverse (PTR) DNS records for your personal computers and mobile/network devices.

Contrary to DNS, NetBIOS to operate does not require to be configured (No need for a domain controller or DNS server). NetBIOS names are registered dynamically when computers and services start and when users log on. Name resolution in a NetBIOS network in a small and self-contained network is broadcast-based.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959262.aspx

Regards,
Florian